# How to echo the uploaded file for a user in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, upload, echo

I have a table for it to stores the file links as it showns: (documents)
it is like:

id | user_id | orig_name | file_name

The pdf files are uploaded correctly but for user_id it gives me constant value.

My goal is to upload a file with admin privilages, and then be able to show different pdf files to different users, with connecting user_id with the id session

I made the session to store the user id. $this->session->userdata('user_id')

Here is my **Upload** contorller:

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
}

function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
    //$config['max_size']   = '10000';
    //$config['max_width']  = '1024';
    //$config['max_height']  = '768';
    $config['encrypt_name']  = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $upload = $this->upload->data();

        $data['upload_data'] = $upload;

        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id'); 

//do I need the user's id or the admin? only the admin can upload files. (admin user is in a different table)

        $this->db->set('user_id', $user_id);
        $this->db->set('file_name', $upload['file_name']);
        $this->db->set('orig_name', $upload['orig_name']);

        $this->db->insert('documents');

        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }
}
```

Thank you for helping me out!
I try to make it clear so if it's a bit complicated then please ask, and I will answer.

Thank you ver much for your help!

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Please edit your question to clarift it.

Answer (score 0):

Do insert like this

```
$data = array(
   'user_id' => $user_id ,
   'file_name' => $upload['file_name'] ,
   'orig_name' => $upload['orig_name']
);

$this->db->insert('documents', $data);
```